# how to draw geodesic on the ellipsoid?

Tags: geodesic

I try to simulate geodesic on the ellipsoid recently.
I have two points on the ellipsoid.
After solving the inverse problem, I can get the distance and two azimuths of two points.
As the figure https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJnUj.jpg. (I can obtain S12 and alpha 1 2)
But how can I draw the geodesic on the ellipsoid?
What I can get from the inverse problem doesn't make sense to me to draw this geodesic path.
Can somebody help me with this question? Thanks!!

Comment: there is no closed form for this. On a sphere, yes. On an ellipsoid, messy. If it is a spheroid, there is, at least, Clairaut's relation. If all three axes are of different lengths then you cannot expect much formally.

Comment: the ellipsoid in this problem is like the Earth so it's biaxial ellipsoid(two axes are the same). I review countless references about geodesic on the ellipsoid and all of them only provide the algorithm of distance and azimuths but even if I have those information, I still cannot draw the geodesic line on the surface. In view of the technology of navigation or something else about path guidance, I am sure that there is a way to draw this line. Can somebody give a hint to me about this problem? THX!!!

Answer (score 0):

Once you have *s*<sub>12</sub> and α<sub>1</sub>, you can
solve a series of direct problems with a fixed φ<sub>1</sub>,
λ<sub>1</sub> and α<sub>1</sub> and a varying
*s*<sub>13</sub> in the range 0 ≤ *s*<sub>13</sub> ≤
*s*<sub>12</sub> to find a sequence of waypoints 3.  Join up these
points and you have your geodesic.

The [GeodSolve](http://geographiclib.sourceforge.net/html/GeodSolve.1.html) utility from [GeographicLib](http://geographiclib.sourceforge.net) will do the job on
the command line (scroll down to the examples section).  Alternatively
use the [GeodesicLine](http://geographiclib.sourceforge.net/html/classGeographicLib_1_1GeodesicLine.html) class in GeographicLib (see the example C++
code provided).  Equivalent functionality is also provided in C by the
[proj.4](https://trac.osgeo.org/proj/) library, version 4.9.1.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a surface of revolution ( two axes of ellipsoid same) by Clairaut's Law it is easy to integrate numerically. The invariant minimum radii are: $r_1 sin \alpha_1 ,r_2 sin \alpha_2 $. If there is no axis-symmetry it is doable, but very cumbersome.